# Urgent - Magento 2.3.4 - "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

Tags: magento2, php, reindex, magento2.3.4, ssl

I am creating a store with Magento, but the products are not appearing, I believe it is due to the error "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.".

I've tried everything a little. I tried to use the command `php bin/magento indexer: reindex` in the root folder of Magento, but it gives an SSL error or something. I tested the command again disabling the error, but a new error appears.

Please, I need to resolve this error soon to continue my work, if anyone can help me, I will be very grateful !!

**I'm using:**

```
Windows -> 10

Magento -> 2.3.4

MAMP -> 4.2.0.23973

PHP -> 7.3.0

MySQL -> 5.7.24
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if php_openssl module is enabled, this module is required by Magento. If enabling the module doesn't help, you may try reinstalling PHP/Magento. Magento prior to proceeding with installation checks if required modules are enabled.